# Is this VPN Kill Switch implementation secure enough?

Tags: linux, networking, security, vpn, iptables

I am using Private Internet Access VPN and it doesn't provide a kill switch for linux distros. So, I have written a simple script using iptables.

After running Wireshark, I found that all the traffic in wlp6s0 was just to and from my public IP (VPN provider's IP). So, I just blocked all other IP's on wlp6s0 so that in case the VPN connection drops, all packets will be dropped.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
IP=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlp6s0 ! -d $IP -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i wlp6s0 ! -s $IP -j DROP
```

This script seems to work. However, I am not sure if there is any other aspect I am overlooking. Can somebody, who knows more about the working of VPN and TUN/TAP, explain if my script is good enough to secure my privacy, in the event of the VPN getting disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

Security-wise, I see a few possible leaks:

1. iptables doesn't block IPv6 traffic at all. You'll want to add ip6tables rules that mirror your iptables rules.
2. It's possible that at some point you'll have a network interface other than wlp6s0 that faces the Internet. To take care of this, I recommend rules that allow traffic to lo and to tun0 (or whatever your VPN interface is), to allow traffic on any interface to the VPN server, and to block all other traffic.
3. You only specify the IP of the VPN server, and not a protocol or port. If the VPN server runs other services too, you're letting traffic go to it in the clear.

There are also a few usability issues with the rules you already have:

1. It looks like you specify your VPN server by hostname and not by IP address. With no exception to your rules for DNS, you won't be able to resolve this hostname if you're not already on the VPN. Obviously, the simplest way around this is to use an IP instead of a hostname, but you might not be able to do that if it's dynamic. Fixing this securely isn't as simple as allowing all DNS traffic to resolver1.opendns.com, since you could then end up leaking all of your DNS traffic to them.
2. You don't have an exception for DHCP, so you won't be able to obtain a dynamic IP address. If you use a static IP address, this doesn't matter, but if you don't, this will result in you not being able to connect to the network.